# Custom PHP app gives Missing Authorization key error

Tags: php, shopify, access-token, shopify-api

I am trying to build a custom Shopify app in my Shopify admin.

I am using [Shopify's official PHP library](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php).

I have successfully initialized the library.

Now when I try to connect to the API I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Shopify\Exception\MissingArgumentException: Missing Authorization key in headers array in /www/doc/www.sozialstar.de/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Auth/OAuth.php:226 Stack trace: #0 /www/doc/www.sozialstar.de/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Utils.php(160): Shopify\Auth\OAuth::getCurrentSessionId(Array, Array, true) #1 /www/doc/www.sozialstar.de/www/script/shopifytest.php(29): Shopify\Utils::loadCurrentSession(Array, Array, true) #2 {main} thrown in /www/doc/www.sozialstar.de/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Auth/OAuth.php on line 226

Here is my PHP code:

```
$requestHeaders = array('api_version'=>'2022-10', 'X-Shopify-Access-Token'=>'mytoken');
$requestCookies = array();
$isOnline = true;

$this->test_session = Utils::loadCurrentSession(
    $requestHeaders,
    $requestCookies,
    $isOnline
);
```

I am doing this based on [Shopify API docs](https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/admin-app-access-tokens).

Why is it not working?

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, Did you solved the issue? if yes, how? Thanks!

Comment: No am still trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Shopify API for PHP [expects you to](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php/blob/7a5b651d276c833101ebb7a43106e55b2e532581/src/Auth/OAuth.php#L219) set the `Authorization` header field/ doesn't support `X-Shopify-Access-Token`. Try this instead:

```
$requestHeaders = array(
                       'api_version'=>'2022-10', 
                       'Authorization'=>'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'
                      );
```

Comment: That changes the error to `Fatal error: Uncaught Shopify\Exception\MissingArgumentException: Missing Bearer token in authorization header in /www/doc/www.sozialstar.de/www/script/vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Auth/OAuth.php:231 Stack trac...`

Comment: That's a good sign. The error means the authorization header is found but that its value doesn't match the expected format (see [line 229 of the getCurrentSessionId](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-php/blob/7a5b651d276c833101ebb7a43106e55b2e532581/src/Auth/OAuth.php#L229) function). Did you replace YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with your access token ? Make sure to pass string formatted as "Bearer" + a space + your access token.

Comment: When I do that, the error changes to this `Fatal error: Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: Wrong number of segments in /www/doc/www.sozialstar.de/www/script/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:102 Sta...` [Screenshot of full error](https://i.ibb.co/JWTBZx5/shopify-api-error.png)

Comment: This is the request header array `$requestHeaders = array('api_version'=>'2022-10', 'Authorization'=>'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');` and yes I replaced YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN with my actual access token.

Comment: According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856459/php-jwt-get-token-wrong-number-of-segments), JWT authorization requires you to send your token in the body of the request. Try `$requestHeaders = array('api_version'=>'2022-10', 'Authorization'=>'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'body'=>'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');` and see how it goes.

Comment: According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856459/php-jwt-get-token-wrong-number-of-segments), JWT authorization requires you to send your token in the body of the request. Try `$requestHeaders = array('api_version'=>'2022-10', 'Authorization'=>'Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN', 'body'=>'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN');` and see how it goes.

Comment: I am still getting the `..Wrong number of segments..` error after trying that.